# Is there a way to simulate MySQL FIND_IN_SET function in SAP Hana?

Tags: hana

here's the thing

I have a procedure just like this one

```
geo_search(latitude, longitude, layers)
```

The `layers` parameter will receive a string with comma separated ids like: `'123,456,789'`, and I need to make a query inside the procedure like an `IN` operation.

I used to do that with `find_in_set(layers, id)` in MySQL. But this function does not exist in Hana.

Does anyone has already been through this?
I've already Googled it but couldn't be able to find a solution.

Thanks in advance

Comment: as these are functions specific to mySQL it would help if you could explain what these functions should achieve. Maybe then we can propose alternatives on SAP HANA.

Comment: find in set returns the index of a value in a comma separated string/array... So `find_in_set('a,b,c,d','c')` would return 3 where as `find_in_set('a,b,c,d','e')` would return 0

Answer (score 1):

One way I found to use something like FIND_IN_SET in Hana was to use LOCATE.
In your case it would be:

```
LOCATE (layers, id) > 0
```